# batch file string character split

Tags: windows, string, character-encoding, batch-file

I want to write a batch file to store a character from a file name into a variable.

For example if my file name is `helloworld` or `how_are_you?`, I want to store fourth character from right into variable `x` (which in the above cases would be `o` and `_`).
File names do not have spaces in my case.

Comment: What environment is this? Windows `cmd` or a Linux shell or something else?

Comment: windows 7 , i wld really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the file name is stored in a variable called `filename`, you can do this:

```
set "rstr=%filename:~-4%"
set "x=%rstr:~0,1%"
```

P.S
If you need `filename` to be passed as a command-line argument (for example, the first), use this before evaluating `rstr` and `x`:

```
set "filename=%1"
```