# Batch Rename rightmost 3 characters

Tags: batch-file, split

This is not working..  No errors.

Have directories:

```
123.abc
123.def
123.ghi
```

Want to rename to:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

What I have done is not working..

I have used: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php
[Renaming Folder Structure in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987109/renaming-folder-structure-in-batch?rq=1)

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /d %%D in ("C:\batch\*") do CALL :RENAME %%D %%~nxD

:RENAME
set "folder=%%~nxD"
rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040473/batch-file-string-character-split
set "x=%folder:~-3%"

FOR /D %%R IN (%1%) DO RENAME %%R "%x%"
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem For each directory under selected folder
    for /d %%d in ("c:\batch\*") do (

        rem Get the extension of the directory if any
        set "name=%%~xd"

        rem If there is a extension
        if defined name (

            rem Remove the dot from extension
            set "name=!name:~1!"

            rem If no file/folder exists with the new name, rename the dir
            if not exist "%%~dpd\!name!" echo ren "%%~fd" "!name!"
        )
    )

    endlocal
```

Final rename command is "echoed" to the console. If output is correct then remove the `echo` from `ren` command line.

Comment: The use of file extensions is pretty slick!  I like this.  Remember, to use, remove the ECHO statement on the Rename line..  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

This will rename the folders to the text after the first period.

Remove the `echo` to activate the command as currently it will only echo the commands to the console.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=." %%a in ('dir "C:\batch" /ad /b ') do echo REN "C:\batch\%%a.%%b" "%%b"
pause
```

Comment: I edited the post as only showing `%%a` did not show the whole folder: e.g 123.  Edited it to be `%%a.%%b` to show 123.abc as this covers the first part - taking the base foldernames.